# Ratchet Websocket Apache2 SSL unable to make connection to PHP websocket

Tags: javascript, php, apache, sockets, ratchet

Been researching the issue with Ratchet over SSL and have been trying to get my Apache2 server configuration working by enabling proxy.load and proxy_wstunnel.load mods.

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled:
     proxy.conf -> ../mods-available/proxy.conf
     proxy.load -> ../mods-available/proxy.load
     proxy_wstunnel.load -> ../mods-available/proxy_wstunnel.load
```

I've added the following line to the end of my apache2.conf:

`ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://domain.com:8080`

The PHP socket-server.php file:

```
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Websocket\SocketControl;
use Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

    $session = new SessionProvider(
        new SocketControl,
        new Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler($memcache)
    );

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                $session
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
```

The relevant JS code that attempts to connect to the socket server:

```
var websocket = {
    wsUri:"wss://domain.com/wss2/NNN",
    socket:null,
    cryptKey:null,
    init:function(){
        try {
            if (typeof MozWebSocket == "function")
                WebSocket = MozWebSocket;
            if ( websocket.socket && websocket.socket.readyState == 1 )
                websocket.socket.close();

            websocket.socket = new WebSocket( websocket.wsUri );
            websocket.socket.onopen = websocket.onopen.bind();
            websocket.socket.onclose = websocket.onclose.bind();
            websocket.socket.onmessage = websocket.onmessage.bind();
            websocket.socket.onerror = websocket.onerror.bind();

        } catch (exception) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + exception);
        }
    },
```

The error I receive when attempting to connect:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com/wss2/NNN' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502`

Answer (score 1):

I guess i am late posting this one, but I have here a working example with routing also. the code is working well as per the latest ratchet version.

```
<?php
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Ratchet\Http\Router;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$routes = new RouteCollection;
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$decorated = new WsServer(new ChatRoom);
$decorated->enableKeepAlive($loop);
$routes->add('chat-room', new Route('/chat-room', array('_controller' => $decorated), array('Origin' => $GLOBALS['Address']), 
    array(), $GLOBALS['Address'], array(), array('GET')));

$decorated = new WsServer(new SingleChat);
$decorated->enableKeepAlive($loop);
$routes->add('single-chat', new Route('/single-chat', array('_controller' => $decorated), array('Origin' => $GLOBALS['Address']), 
    array(), $GLOBALS['Address'], array(), array('GET')));

$decorated = new WsServer(new Ratchet\Server\EchoServer);
$decorated->enableKeepAlive($loop);
$routes->add('echo', new Route('/echo', array('_controller' => $decorated), array('Origin' => $GLOBALS['Address']), 
    array(), $GLOBALS['Address'], array(), array('GET')));


$app = new HttpServer(new Router(new UrlMatcher($routes, new RequestContext)));

$secure_websockets = new \React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8091', $loop);
$secure_websockets = new \React\Socket\SecureServer($secure_websockets, $loop, [
    'local_cert' => 'path/to/certificate.crt',
    'local_pk' => '/path/to/your-key.key',
    'verify_peer' => false
]);

$secure_websockets_server = new \Ratchet\Server\IoServer($app, $secure_websockets, $loop);
$secure_websockets_server->run();
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for a secure websocket application myself as well...
Perhaps a cleaner setup. No need to proxy. Here's what I figured out:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// SSL configuration
$context = array(
    'tls' => array(
        'local_cert' => "-path-to-ssl-certificate.crt",
        'local_pk' => "-path-to-ssl-privatekeyfile.key",
        'allow_self_signed' => true, // Set to false in production
        'verify_peer' => false
    )
);

// Set up websocket server
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$application = new Ratchet\App('your.domain.com', 8443, 'tls://0.0.0.0', $loop, $context);

// Set up controller component (instance of MessageComponentInterface or WsMessageComponentInterface)
$controller = new MyControllerObject();
$application->route('/any_desired_path', $controller, array('*'));

$application->run();
die('-server stopped-');
```

Now you can set up your client secure websocket connection, and get your application running!

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss:your.domain.com:8443/any_desired_path');
```

Note: the SSL setup can be hard, as no error messages appear e.g. when the crt or key file are missing, or the allow_self_signed/verify_peer values are non-boolean. The client simply closes the connection, or is unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the URL you are using:

```
wsUri:"wss://domain.com/wss2/NNN",
```

you could try:

```
wsUri:"wss://domain.com/wss2",
```

since you link to that URL in your config